# Cookies not deleted

Tags: php, cookies

Strange issue.

This is index.php:

```
session_start();
print_r($_COOKIE);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

This is logout.php:

```
session_destroy();
$_COOKIE['key'] = "";
$_COOKIE['usr_email'] = "";
setcookie("key", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie("usr_email", "", time() - 3600);
header("Location: http://www.site.net/index.php");
```

When I load logout.php, after being redirected to index.php I get:

```
Array
(
    [fc] => fcVal=6927578914025605120
    [PHPSESSID] => na015ipu3s69hhj00sgd0h1es6
)
Array
(
    [key] => cc2bffe0c1e36bc5790f5b78b11e5f50
    [usr_email] => myemail@gmail.com
)
```

Sessions are ok as I generate them when I load index.php, but how are the cookie still present?

**Note**

I have some more code on index.php that determines if the login form was filled and starts to authenticate the user, if the user/pass are correct it sets two session vars and two cookie vars (usr_email and key).

At the moment, I'm after the login form, so I have both cookies and session vars and since the cookies were not being deleted, I disabled every other PHP code that was on the index page as I thought maybe something is automatically logging me in. So currently I have authenticated and then commented out the rest from the index page that is not what mentioned above.

**Also relevant**
This is how I set the cookies when a user is authenticated:

```
    setcookie("key", $cookie['key'], time() + 36000);
    setcookie("usr_email", $cookie['usr_email'], time() + 36000);
```

PHP Version: PHP 5.3.6-13

**Last edit**

As Josh wrote in the comments, I was confusing the cookie print with the session, I wasn't able to delete the session vars and not the cookie vars.

Comment: Have you tried `exit`ing the script after the header: Location?

Comment: @TimWolla - just tried, does not change anything.

Comment: Don't use relative times for your cookie deletion timestamp. That presumes that the user's clock is (relatively) accurate. Set a fixed "Jan 1/1970 00:00:00 GMT" type timestamp, so that even machines with utterly broken clocks should most likely honor it.

Comment: @MarcB will do that, thanks! However this is not the case here, even though I empty the cookies using ``$_COOKIE['usr_email'] = ""`` I can still see the value after the redirect

Comment: In index.php, you have cookies, *then* session variables, printed to screen. Isn't `key`, and `usr_email` in session according to the order that you printed them? Not in the cookies?

Comment: @Josh Nice catch, can't believe I missed that one! You're right, the usr_email/key are in the session, so that raises two different questions, why do I have ``PHPSESSID`` and ``fc`` in my cookie var and why doesn't the ``session_destroy()`` remove the session vars?

Comment: @josh: writing to the cookie superglobal doesn't trigger a cookie header to be sent. Any 'write' changes to _COOKIE affect only the server-side script. Only a setcookie() call will send updated cookie values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> ... [session_destroy()] does not unset any of the global variables associated with
> the session, **or unset the session cookie**...
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, **like to log the user out**, the
> session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
> session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
> deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

**Note:** `PHPSESSID` is the cookie propagating the session ID.

Try the following to clear your session variables from being reused:

```
// Example #1 Destroying a session with $_SESSION
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

**Note:** `session_start()` must be called before `session_destroy()` can work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating cookies in sub directory? If so make sure you have added the cookie path. Here is an example

```
setcookie("usr_email", "", time() - 3600, '/directory-name/');
```